# Azure Cli get specific device twin

Tags: azure-cli, azure-iot-hub

Does someone know why I receive this table instead of my IotHub device twin with the [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/device-twin?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-device-twin-show) ?

```
$iothub_name = 'iot-eu-iot-sandbox96587.azure-devices.net'
$device_id = 'SimulatedDevice'
az iot hub device-twin show --hub-name $iothub_name --device-id $device_id
```

[image]

Comment: replace `$iothub_name` with AzureIOtHbName and `$device_id`
 with `AzureDeviceiD` [Output](https://i.imgur.com/vo82HRU.png)

Comment: This does the same: az iot hub device-twin show --hub-name 'iot-eu-iot-sandbox.azure-devices.net' --device-id 'SimulatedDevice'

Comment: Keep only  `iot-eu-iot-sandbox96587`

Comment: That doesn't work, same result, I receive the table

Comment: `az iot hub device-twin show --hub-name 'iot-eu-iot-sandbox96587' --device-id 'SimulatedDevice' --output json`
`

Comment: That works ! Why is this not the default display ?

Comment: The global defaults should be JSON, so you've just found a bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Adding `--output json` to  `az iot hub device-twin show`   command from the    [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/hub/device-twin?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-hub-device-twin-show)  displayed the output in `Json`.
- The command gets a device twin of IoTHub.
- Thanks @MatthijsvanderVeer for your comment on the default display.

```bash
az iot hub device-twin show --hub-name $iothub_name --device-id $device_id --output json
```

**Output:**
[image]